# Azure pipeline using matrix environment variable in step condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps pipeline I have the following:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    unit_test_linux:
      imageName: 'ubuntu-16.04'
      TYPE: 'unit'
    cucumber:
      imageName: 'ubuntu-16.04'
      TYPE: 'cucumber'
```

I want to use `TYPE` in a step condition, a bit like below, how do I do this?

```
- bash: |
    set -ev
    cd ./client
    npm install
  displayName: install
  env:
    DISPLAY: ':99.0'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'), eq(${{'TYPE'}}, 'unit'))``
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix variable is like every variable, so in this way:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'), eq(variables['TYPE'], 'unit'))
```

Comment: It is **not** like _every_ variable. It is only available on _runtime_, just to clarify. For example you can't use matrix variables in conditional templates. But you can use them in those place where _runtime_ variables are allowed. _Compile time_ variables (such as `variables['Agent.IS']`) can be used anywhere. More details can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079112/how-to-reference-an-azure-devops-matrix-variable-inside-an-expression

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich good point, thanks!

Comment: Is there some way to do it with `- ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux') }}:` syntax instead? My goal is to *not* spam all other agents with a skipped step in their list.