# How to reference an Azure DevOps matrix variable, inside an expression?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to access an Azure DevOps matrix variable, in a compile time expression. The reference value is always null/empty/missing. Like the variable hasn't been set.

here's a sample yml file I was trying:

```
jobs:
- job: LinuxBuild
  displayName: Pew Pew
  strategy:
    matrix:
      debugJob:
        buildConfiguration: Debug
      releaseJob:
        buildConfiguration: Release
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

 steps:
  - script: echo ${{variables.debugJob.buildConfiguration}} ## <-- always null/empty

  - script: echo ${{variables['debugJob.buildConfiguration']}}  ## <-- always null/empty

  - ${{ if eq(variables.debugJob.buildConfiguration, 'Debug') }}: ## <-- never ran/executed
    - template: doSomething.yml@templates
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For keywords `Matrix`, it is used to [expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline) the multi-configs into multiple runtime jobs. In another word, the YAML which contain the `Matrix` keywords will be expanded at **runtime** instead of `parse time`. So, the variable `buildConfiguration` is a **runtime variable**, and it is not available at compile time, also can not be get then.

Also, `${{ }}` is a format which to process the variables at **compile time**.

Now, there's no doubt to know that the issue you met is a expected action since you are trying to get a **runtime variable** at **compile time**.

---

So, to print out the value of `buildConfiguration`, you need use the format of `$()`

Change your YAML script to this:

```
jobs:
- job: LinuxBuild

  displayName: Pew Pew
  strategy:
    matrix:
      debugJob:
        buildConfiguration: Debug
      releaseJob:
        buildConfiguration: Release
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

  steps:
  - script: echo $(buildConfiguration) 

  - script: echo "hello"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.buildConfiguration, 'Debug'))
```

---

Now, let's focus on the another try you made: `- ${{ if eq(variables.debugJob.buildConfiguration, 'Debug') }}:`.

Firstly, you need know that `${{ if xxx }}`, this is a `template expression` which processed at **compile time**. This means, the system will go parsing the value then decide whether next steps/jobs/templates should be ran. This process are happen before pipeline run. We call that **initial** step.

As I mentioned above, `buildConfiguration` is a **runtime** variable. It only available at run time. So, its value could not be get at compile time. In compile time, its value will be parsed into `null`. This is why you template never be ran.

There has 2 work arounds you can consider to make this condition true.

**1)** Change to use another variable in condition, the one which can available at both compile time and run time. e.g `Build.SourceBranchName`.

**2)** Split the condition and change them into the tasks' `condition` which defined in template yml file.

Like:

```
  - script: echo "hello"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.buildConfiguration, 'Debug'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. The matrix variables being `runtime variables` was my gut feeling - so I'm glad that has been confirmed. What I was _really hoping_ for was an answer for the last part -> conditional template. I was using a `compile time` template expression, which can't/doesn't work. So now I'm unsure how to have a conditional template based on a MATRIX variable.

Comment: Further more, I can't use suggestion #1 - because the matrix defines the variable. Not a global variables for the entire pipeline. As for suggestion #2 - that only works on various `steps` ... but the `template` step doesn't have a `condition` allowed on it. Which was why i was trying to leverage `compile time` or `run time` expressions.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Limited by the variable you were using is a runtime variable. No way to get it at compile time. If you change to use another variable, that would be much easy.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Nope, for suggestion #2, what I mean is put condition onto one specific step. For example, there has one powershell task in template, then I make that condition to powershell task. I know this way verrry trouble, but I would say it works.

Comment: correct. i know the `condition` works for every step. This now means: all "runs" in the matrix (in my scenarion, run 1 == Debug, run 2 == Release) will -all- include/run that template .. but only one of them will actually _do_ each `step`. (the step will say `condition: skip if RELEASE`). So Release will have all this extra noise in the logs. skip / skip / skip / skip / .. etc... I thought (actually, HOPED and PRAYED) that this would be a feature of Azure DevOps pipelines. If it's not - where do we pray/ask for this feature?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Another thing you need pay attention to is, template is expanded at **compile time** . If you want the condition work to template file, then the variable which can work at compile time is necessary.

Comment: @Pure.Krome I’m sooory for I missed your latest comment. Go this [community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), you can raise your suggestion there. It is the forum that our product group reviewed.